# How can I change what happens when "enter" key is pressed on a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

when I am editing a cell and press enter the next row is automatically selected, I want to stay with the current row... I want to happen nothing except the EndEdit.

I have this:

```
private void dtgProductos_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            dtgProductos[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Selected = true; //this line is not working
            var index = dtgProductos.SelectedRows[0].Cells.IndexOf(dtgProductos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]);
            switch (index)
            {
                case 2:
                    {
                        dtgProductos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Selected = true;
                        dtgProductos.BeginEdit(true);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    {
                        dtgProductos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Selected = true;
                        dtgProductos.BeginEdit(true);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    {
                        btnAddProduct.Focus();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

so when I edit a row that is not the last one I get this error:

```
Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to override ProcessEnterKey to not advance focus to the next row.

Maybe [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/csharplanguage/thread/359fb658-57ae-438c-b6c8-4be213a20dd5) will help.

Comment: I am unable to find which method to override, can you help me on this?

Comment: now I got it... I left the override method empty but I still got the error =(

Comment: Added a link that I found googling phrase "changing default behavior of enter key datagridview" (because advancing a row is the default behavior).