# How to prevent an Enter key press from ending EditMode in a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a custom DataGridView control in a Windows-Forms application.  When a user presses the Enter key, I do not want anything to happen.  I have already overridden the OnKeyPress method in my custom DataGridView to prevent the SelectedCell property from changing.  This works alright when a cell is selected but not being editted.  However, if a cell is in Edit mode when Enter is pressed, the CellEndEdit event is still fired and the SelectedCell property is subsequently changed.

How can I stop the Enter key from ending Edit Mode on my DataGridView control?

Comment: I am afraid that the only way you have to account for what happens during the edit mode is hooking the keys (as far a there is no event allowing you to have full control on this situation). Here you have a post (in C#) which links to what seems to be a solution for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527371/how-can-i-change-what-happens-when-enter-key-is-pressed-on-a-datagridview

Comment: thanks, using your link I found the answer I was looking for!

Comment: I am happy of having been of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer, thanks to [varocarbas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2480047/varocarbas), who commented below my original question.  My assumption is that the CellEndEdit Event is fired somewhere following the ProcessCmdKeys() method-call but before the OnKeyPress() call due to the precedence of the ENTER key being higher than a normal key (it's a Command key). This explains why I was unable to change the behavior while a cell was still in EditMode using OnKeyPress().

The custom DataGridView that I created, which prevents *any* action from occurring following an ENTER-key press in a DataGridView, can be seen below:

```
Public Class clsModifyDataGridView
   Inherits Windows.Forms.DataGridView

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Changes the behavior in response to a Command-precedence key press
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <returns>True if we handled the key-press, otherwise dependent on default behavior</returns>
   Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
      ' Was the ENTER key pressed?
      If keyData = Keys.Enter Then     ' YES
          ' DO NOTHING 
          Return True
       End If

       ' Handle all other keys as usual
       Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
   End Function
End Class
```

Somebody please correct me if my assumption about the call-sequence is inadequate.  Also note, this ProcessCmdKey() override made my previously mentioned override of the OnKeyPress() method unnecessary.

Comment: ProcessCmdKey is called before anything else (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx)